# Install Program Stoq (Python) in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk

I am having great difficulty installing Stoq program in Windows 7.
It was originally designed for Linux, but because it was developed in Python and have all libraries for Windows should not be so difficult.

This is the list of Requirements:

Gtk+ >= 2.20

Gudev >= 147

Kiwi = 1.9.39.2

Mako >= 0.2.5

PostgresSQL >= 8.4

PyGtk >= 2.20

PySerial >= 2.1

Python >= 2.5

Python Cairo = 1.8.2

Python Dateutil >= 1.4.1

Python Poppler 0.12.1

Python Twisted >= 10.0

Python XLWT >= 0.7.2

Python Imaging Library (PIL) >= 1.1.5

PyWebkitGtk = (1, 1, 7)

Psycopg >= 2.0.5

Reportlab >= 2.4

Stoqdrivers = 0.9.21

Storm >= 0.19

Zope.interface >= 3.0

WeasyPrint >= 0.15

The Github is https://github.com/stoq/stoq

Thank all in advance.

Comment: There is no actual question here. Also, this site is for programming questions (usually "how do I install XYZ?" is not a programming question).

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not correct. This is an open source program and I have a problem to implement in windows. My idea is to create an developer environment in windows. So I thought I ask here favorable.

Comment: Well, you still need to write an actual question if you want an answer... What did you try, how did it fail, what do you need help with?